# The UIButton on UIToolBar seems to be not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Here's my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 30, height: 30))
    button1.setTitle("hi", for: .normal)
    button1.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
    button1.setTitleColor(.black, for: .highlighted)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.barItem2Clicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    button1.backgroundColor=UIColor.red

    let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button1)
    toolBar1.items?.append(barButton1)
}
```

method `barItem2Clicked` :

```
func barItem2Clicked(sender :Any?) {
    NSLog("hello")
}
```

I wanted to use UIButton add to UIToolBar, but the action of `button1` can not be called, and the Highlighted effect is not shown too.

I clicked the `button1` I just added, but the method `barItem2Clicked` never called.

Did I missed something?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you add the target to the bar button item? What is the frame of the bar button item?

Comment: You don't have a reference any more to your UIButton. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45385689/6167296

Comment: Thank you guys, I think my code of the frame of the button is not the main reason of this problem, I changed the frame `CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 30, height: 30)` to `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)`, the toolBar can fix it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the toolBar1 is connected
I just tried with your code and it seems to be working.

[image]

Comment: Did the method `barItem2Clicked` called? I builed a new project to test the code, and the method still can't be called.

Comment: Hi @Loyoan, the method gets called and it logs hello in the console. i checked it, may be if you want you can send me your code and i can see what is wrong there. you can push it to git so that i can check.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i build several projects to test, i think it's a bug of Xcode. I open the first project and add some constrains to the toolbar then delete them all, then  IT'S WORKING, i don't know why but it's finally working. Thank you for verifying my code.