# Origin position of UIBarButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to know Y and X position of `UIBarButtons` and preferably its width and height.

I've tried with this solution: [UIBarButtonItem: How can I find its frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318368/uibarbuttonitem-how-can-i-find-its-frame) but it doesn't work for me.

I tried:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *item = _bbiPlus ;
 UIView *view = [item valueForKey:@"view"];

 NSLog(@"igrek? %f", view.frame.origin.y);
```

With output:

```
0.000.
```

How could i get position of `item` considering that it changes on different devices?

Comment: can you please try your luck with :

`view.layer.frame.origin.y`
or
`view.layer.position`
or
`view.center`

Comment: @amorbytes unfortunately still 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need use UIBarButtonItem with custom view, to have pointer at that view (`valueForKey:@"view"]` smells like private API: can be rejected, doesn't guarantee 100% result).
You need use `convertRect:` functions to get coordinates in view relative to which you need coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[self.view convertPoint:yourButton.origin toView:nil];
```

or in another words

```
[view.superview convertPoint:navButton.frame.origin toView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view]
```